# startActivityForResult to one class and have that class return the data to a different class?

Tags: java, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I have 3 classes: MainActivity, HighScoreActivity, and GameScreenActivity. I want to go to the GameScreenActivity via MainActivity, and then when the game has finished, pass the score to the HighScoreActivity. Everything gets passed to the GameScreenActivity successfully, but it doesn't go to the onActivityResult in HighScoreActivity.

I believe it's because of the MainActivity having the startActivityForResult, so the GameScreenActivity's finishQuiz() is expecting to return its data to the MainActivity. How would I pass the GameScreenActivity's data to the HighScoreActivity?

MainActivity()

```
    MainActivity(){
    ...
        private void startQuiz() {
            String difficulty = spinnerDifficulty.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), GameScreenActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DIFFICULTY, difficulty);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_QUIZ);
        }
    }
```

GameScreenActivity()

```
    GameScreenActivity(){
    ...
        private void finishQuiz(){
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), 
    HighScoreActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SCORE, score);
            resultIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_DIFFICULTY, difficulty);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            startActivity(resultIntent);
        }
    }
```

HighScoreActivity()

```
    HighScoreActivity(){
    ...
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
    Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_QUIZ){
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    int score = data.getIntExtra(GameScreenActivity.EXTRA_SCORE, 0);
                    String difficulty = data.getStringExtra(GameScreenActivity.EXTRA_DIFFICULTY);
                    if (score > highScore10) {
                        updateHighscore(score, difficulty);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

*-------------------------------------------------------------*

Trying with the Broadcast method:

GameScreenActivity() with broadcasting methods

```
    GameScreenActivity(){
    ...
        private void finishQuiz(){
            Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
            Intent intent = new Intent("scoreEvent");
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DIFFICULTY, difficulty);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SCORE, score);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            Intent goToHighScores = new Intent(getBaseContext(), HighScoreActivity.class);
            startActivity(goToHighScores);
        }
    }
```

HighScoreActivity() with broadcasting methods

```
    HighScoreActivity(){
    ...
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_high_score);

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                    new IntentFilter("scoreEvent"));
        }


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
    Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_QUIZ){
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    int score = data.getIntExtra(GameScreenActivity.EXTRA_SCORE, 0);
                    String difficulty = data.getStringExtra(GameScreenActivity.EXTRA_DIFFICULTY);
                    if (score > highScore10) {
                        updateHighscore(score, difficulty);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering `HighScoreActivity` is running,
You can utilize `LocalBroadcastManager` to register local broadcastReceiver in `HighScoreActivity` with `IntentFilter`. Also, **don't forget to unregister** in `onDestroy()`

Now, instead of `setResult` do `sendBroadcast()` from `GameScreenActivity`

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: I tried to change the code, I edited the post to include it. Is that right? It's not working and I think I might be missing something (I tried going through a tutorial of it)

Comment: As i mentioned in answer, you need HighScoreActivity runnning, you are firing LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast() before activity is alive. After seeing your code.. you can directly putExtras in intent that starts HighScoreActivity

Comment: Oh right sorry. This might sound silly but how would I get HighScoreActivity to run if I'm not actively in it?

Comment: Can you try this, 
Intent goToHighScores=new Intent(getBaseContext(),HighScoreActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DIFFICULTY, difficulty);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SCORE, score);
startActivity(goToHighScores);

then in HighScoreActivity do getIntent() and get you data from that intent. you dont need broadcastReceiver i guess.. just comment it out for now.